# place filenames of all files inside a folder into a textfile

Tags: file-management

I'm working on organizing a big music library of songs and I want to "rate" them and write down some other information about each song inside a text file. I'd like to have a system where I have a program that scans a folder and takes all the filenames of each mp3 file and places them inside a text(.txt) file, each on it's own line. Is this possible in windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned which OS, but assuming Windows you can use PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "*path to your library*" -Recurse -Filter "*.mp3" | Export-Csv "*path to the text file*"
```

This will create the file, however, as you add more files you may not be able to update the file automatically without overwriting your extra information.

You might consider creating a database for this instead (see [MySQL Community Edition](https://www.mysql.com/products/community/) or [SQL Server Express Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express)).

Comment: yes I'm using windows 7. I've thought about creating a database for this purpose but I'm often not on the same machine or network even so synchronizing it would be a big hassle. I'm currently just adding new music to new folders and once I'm finished with a folder I can just run your command and generate a file and move on to placing my music inside a new folder.

Comment: From a cmd prompt type: dir /b <path>\*.mp3 > <path>\filename.txt